# how to reshape dataframe in python pandas

Tags: python, arrays, pandas

Can anyone suggest an efficient way of reshaping a column (in a python pandas dataframe) into multiple columns, with alternating column assignment. I could do this with a loop but wondering if there is a more elegant way. For an example, consider the following example:

```
Col
1 
2  
3  
4  
5  
6 
7  
8
```

to

```
x1 x2 x3
1 2 3
2 3 4
3 4 5
4 5 6
5 6 7
6 7 8
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [strides](https://rigtorp.se/2011/01/01/rolling-statistics-numpy.html) with `DataFrame` constructor and [`DataFrame.to_numpy`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html) :

```
def rolling_window(a, window):
    shape = a.shape[:-1] + (a.shape[-1] - window + 1, window)
    strides = a.strides + (a.strides[-1],)
    return np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(a, shape=shape, strides=strides)


df = pd.DataFrame(rolling_window(df['Col'].to_numpy(), 3), 
                  columns=['col1','col2','col3'])
print (df)
   col1  col2  col3
0     1     2     3
1     2     3     4
2     3     4     5
3     4     5     6
4     5     6     7
5     6     7     8
```

EDIT: For oldier pandas versions use [`DataFrame.values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.values.html) for convert column to `1d array`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(rolling_window(df['Col'].values, 3), 
                  columns=['col1','col2','col3'])
print (df)
```

Comment: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'to_numpy'

Comment: df = pd.DataFrame(rolling_window(normalized.to_numpy(), 3),                                                  'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'to_numpy'

Comment: @MuhammadRusli - Answer was edited, it seems your pandas is a bit old